# Stack runtime error

Tags: c++, stack, runtime-error

```
#include <stack>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::stack<std::function<int()>> s;
    s.push(main);
    return s.top()();
}
```

I get the following diagnostic:

```
result: runtime error        time: 0.04s    memory: 39704 kB     signal: 11 (SIGSEGV)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 6):

First, you aren't allowed to call `main` yourself. Secondly, it appears to be doing "what you'd expect" and making the call, so you're causing infinite recursion which uses up all your stack space and then overflows it.

Answer (score 1):

Standard answer: N3485 § 3.6.1/3

> The function main shall not be used within a program.

That's pretty self-explanatory.